# Error connecting to RDS from Rest APIs deployed to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have created a simple .NET 6 Web API that connects to a database and returns data. I deployed it to an S3 bucket using the Publish to AWS Lambda option inside Visual Studio. I also created a simple PostgreSQL database on an RDS instance in the same AWS region/account. The RDS is setup with public access set to true.

I am able to run my API locally and connect to the RDS which returns data without errors. However, when I run the API from the S3 bucket they are not able to connect to the RDS. It returns a 500 error: Error from cloudfront.

Is there additional configurations I need to setup within AWS to allow my APIs in the S3 bucket to connect to the RDS instance?

Comment: S3 is purely a storage mechanism that can serve your files to the browser.  S3 isn't involved in anything else.  Your browser may later make a connection to, in this case, RDS.  Can you show the browser logs?  What is it trying to do?  It's possible you have a CORS issue but it's unclear from your question.

Comment: The only thing I can see in the Network section of chrome dev tools is:

`name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "OK"`

Are there different logs I can look at?

As far as setting up CORS, I did setup CORS to allow for the angular UI site to connect to the API and that works fine. I can have the API return static data to the UI without issue. But I did not add any CORS setup in the API for the RDS. I did not think I needed to. Again, I am able to connect with the API locally to the RDS in AWS. But the API in AWS cannot connect with the RDS in AWS.

Comment: After testing the API more with Swagger, the following is being returned:

Error: response status is 500 

content-length: 0 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Thu,14 Jul 2022 22:33:22 GMT 
 errortype: NotSupportedException 
 x-cache: Error from cloudfront

Comment: I would not expect to have CloudFront in front of RDS.  In front of your S3 bucket would be fine.  When you say API, what does that mean?  Can you give a bit of insight into that?

Comment: Cloudfront is not in front of the RDS. I deployed APIs to an S3 bucket behind an API gateway which tries to connect to the RDS. For the APIs, I followed this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiQMrH9HF_s

Comment: This is not about S3, S3 used to store bins that later used to create Lambda, Can you share logs from your Lambda function that executes API? Most likely missing IAM policies (permissions)..

Comment: I am not sure if I have access to those logs. Would they be in CloudWatch?